# How to transform array of object into more advanced array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, reduce

I'm looking for solution of my little problem in JS.
I have array of objects

```
[
 { "id": "id-1", "weight": 345 },
 { "id": "id-2", "weight": 500 },
 { "id": "id-3", "weight": 300 }
]
```

and I want to get array as on picture

```
[
  {
    "orderID" : "uniqueID",
    "load" : [
       { "id" "id-1", "weight": 345 },
       { "id" "id-2", "weight": 500 },
    ]
  },
  {
    "orderID" : "uniqueID",
    "load" : [
       { "id" "id-3", "weight": 300 }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to divide packages onto loads (each loads no more than 1000 of weight)

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour].

Comment: [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) Your problem is not such trivial

Comment: What determines which of the first objects go in which of the "load" arrays?

Comment: As @CertainPerformance mentioned, you should try to solve this first, so I am gonna give you few pointers.

 1. Create a new empty array that you can insert your loads.
 2. Iterate through the original array.
 3. Create a variable that holds the total amount
 4. Check the value of total amount and insert if it fits.

Comment: it doesn't matter. I should check first, add to first order object (load array), then check second do the same, and third when total weight in first load is biggest than 1000 create new order and load. if input array has more than 3 object it should works the same (second order shouldn't has more than 1000 o fweight)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array.reduce for grouping:

```js
var arr = [
 { "id": "id-1", "weight": 345 },
 { "id": "id-2", "weight": 500 },
 { "id": "id-3", "weight": 300 }
];

var res = arr.reduce((m, o, i) => {
    var lastPushedElement = m[m.length - 1];
    var totLoad = lastPushedElement.load.reduce((s, e) => s + e.weight, 0);
    if ((totLoad + o.weight) <= 1000) {
        lastPushedElement.load.push(o);
    } else {
        m.push({ orderID: i + 1, load: [o] });
    }
    return m;
}, [{ orderID: 0, load: [] }]);

console.log(res);
```